# How do I get the longest continuous sequence in a matrix which fulfills a criterion?

Tags: clojure

I have a matrix in which every vector consists of hashmaps. Here's a toy example:

```
[
    [{:label x, ...}, {:label y, ...}, ...]
    [{:label y, ...}, {:label z, ...}, ...]
    [{:label p, ...}, {:label x, ...}, ...]
    ...
    [{:label x, ...}, {:label x, ...}, ...]
]
```

Because only the label is relevant to my problem, I have removed the other things.

Now, what I want to do is for each row, calculate the longest sequence of continuous labels. That is, if the labels of a row are `A B B B A A C A`, then the longest sequence is `B B B`. What I then want to return is a tuple of 1) which row `k` has the longest such sequence (any of the longest is fine in case of a tie), and also 2) what the index `i` of the first item in the sequence is, as well as 3) what the index `j` of the last item in the sequence is.

So, for this simplified matrix, that would be `k = 1, i = 2, j = 5`.

```
[
    [A B B A A C]
    [C B A A A A]
    [B A C A B A]
]
```

I'm new to functional programming and I really like it so far, but I can't quite figure out how to do this without resorting to e.g. the foreach loops of my native php. I'm not looking for somebody to do everything for me, but a hint in the right direction would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: maybe `(partition-by identity ..)` would help https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition-by

Comment: Ooh, sounds like it, thanks! I'm going to bed now but I'll definitely have a closer look at that in the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```clj
(def m "ABBAAAC")

(->> m (map-indexed vector)  
       (partition-by #(-> % second identity))
       (sort-by count >) 
       (first))
```

Gives:

```
([3 \A] [4 \A] [5 \A])
```

Comment: WOHO INTERNET POINTS! \ o /